# Connect computers in a network, via hub or through another computer?

Tags: networking, hub, infrastructure

I'm using an internet hub to connect broadband and computers. When setting up a home network (for some simple file sharing), I can choose

1. *"this computer connect to internet through another computer"* or
2. *"this computer and other computers connect to internet through an internet hub"*

I think each computer will get less bandwidth quota if choose the first one, so I tend to choose the second option.

Windows recommends the first one though. What would you recommend, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your setup. It is the fastest if you can connect directly with your modem. When you connect through another PC it adds delay to the connection and if the PC is down you don't have internet connection.

So, the setup I would recommend is:

> Internet ↔ Modem ↔ Hub/Switch ↔ PCs

Answer (score 2):

By "hub" you likely mean "switch" - an actual hub is pretty hard to find these days.

and by "through anouther pc" i think you mean ICS (internet connection sharing).

Neither method is "faster". But if you use ICS youll need PC A to be turned on for PC B to get internet access.

I'd say go with robert's suggestion and buy a small switch. They are dirt cheap and will give you the best outcome.

Comment: I think he is talking about the homegroup internet sharing, its some random Microsoft terminology. By the way if he actually means internet hub as in hardware based he is is probably talking about a router not a switch.

Comment: true. Could mean just about anything, really. :)

Comment: I would guess Jenny means a combined ADSL-modem/Router/WAP/Ethernet-switch. These are ubiquitous in my part of the world.

Comment: It's an old hub(broadband plugin upper-line, each computer plugin down-line ). Windows provide "HomeGroup". Thanks for the above info. I will use the "hub" setting then.